# Pandas: iterate through a list to match values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm working with a dataframe of covid counts for all counties in the US. I've figured out how to isolate one county and export the result to a csv like this:

```
import pandas as pd
covid = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv')
agh = covid[covid['county'] == 'Allegheny']
agh.to_csv('AlleghenyCovid.csv')
```

Now I want to create a list of counties like this:

```
countyList = covid.county.unique()
```

and loop through them to create a csv for each. That's where I'm stuck. How can I use a list of known values to iterate through the dataframe and create new dataframes from each iteration? I've been thinking something like:

```
for i in countyList:
    if covid['county'] == i:
        ...
```

but that gives an ambiguous value error. I'm not sure exactly what needs to be defined.

Comment: This has been asked many times in pandas. Look into `groupby`: `for i,g in covid.groupby(['county']): g.to_csv(i+'Covid.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution iterate unique list of `county` column:

```
for name in covid.county.unique()
    covid.loc[covid.county == name,:].to_csv(name+'.csv')
```

For each county named by `name`:

- we are selecting rows from dataframe `covid` where `county` is equal to `name`
- then such selection is saved to CSV file named: `name`+`.csv`.

Comment: This answer needs more information as to what this code is actually doing.